# Reuse variables in akka config

Tags: scala, akka, config

How can I reuse a config property in a couple of other properties? My simplified real-world example looks like this:

```
myApp {

  host = "www.myfoohost.com"

  urls {
    url1 = host + "/b" // this...
    url2 = host + "/a" // ... and this do not work
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's called [substitutions](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/README.md#uses-of-substitutions) in Typesafe Config, which uses the `${}` notation:

```
myApp {
  host = "www.myfoohost.com"

  urls {
    url1 = ${myApp.host}"/b"
    url2 = ${myApp.host}"/a"
  }
}
```